# Can I convert an ArrayDataProvider into ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

Good evening everyone, I am using the ExportMenu component, which I believe only works with a dataprovider that comes from ActiveDataprovider.

In my case, I have an ArrayDataProvider, can I convert it to ActiveDataProvider?

If yes how?
Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to use specifically `ActiveDataProvider` for ExportMenu. Anything that implements `DataProviderInterface` should work including `ArrayDataProvider`.

Comment: Are you sure? then I don't understand why, if I pass my dataProvider to the ExportMenu of my view, and click on "Export," it doesn't bring up the results.
My gridview is paged, but the problem is that the export of the first page doesn't work either.
Could you tell me why?

Comment: Yes, even [its documentation](https://demos.krajee.com/export#option-dataProvider) mentions that it's `DataProviderInterface` what's needed. Sorry, but without any related code/error message I can't really tell what is wrong in your case. Try adding [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $x,
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => $this->perPage,
                    'page' => $page
                ],
            ]);
            return $this->renderPartial("...php", 'dataprovider' => $dataprovider)

and ExportMenu in this renderPartial (default ExportMenu) but when i click on "Export csv", the export doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using `renderPartial()`? If you use `renderPartial()` the registered JS are not injected into rendered HTML because it's expected that `render()` will be used later. Missing JS files might be reason why ExportMenu is not working. If you don't want to render whole layout because the action is called through ajax to generate part of page you should use `renderAjax()` instead. It's similar to `renderPartial()` but it will still include JS/CSS files registered in the rendered view.